# Error  while adding a new group in sfDoctrineGuardPlugin

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, sfdoctrineguard

i am new to symfony.i am using symfony1.4 and Doctrine . While adding a new group in `sfDoctrineGuardPlugin` i am getting this error `The item has not been saved due to some errors.`i don't know why i am getting this error. how to find these errors? Any one please help me...
 thanks in advance

Comment: Does this happen in both dev and production environments? Look for log entries in symfony's own log directory, and the main PHP error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the problem because my $form->isValid() returns false to see the errors i used the following code

```
<?php
        $errors = $form->getErrorSchema()->getErrors();
        if (count($errors) > 0)
        echo 'List of Errors:' . '<br>;
        {
            foreach ($errors as $name => $error)
            {
            echo $name . ': ' . $error . '<BR>';
            }
        }
 ?>
```